# Detecting if an image was generated from unlicensed software

Tags: adobe-photoshop, license, adobe-illustrator

I am not a hardcore graphic designer but I’m knowledgeable in the use of some graphic design tools like Adobe Photoshop and Illustrator.

Let’s say I use pirated/unlicensed copy of these software since I seldom use them, then my question is:

Is it possible to determine an image—any graphic output from this software—was made from an unlicensed/pirated software? If not then when would these software publishers will know about it?

Comment: Why the "legal" tag on this question, when it is clearly illegal to do what you are suggesting with the software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to determine an image (any graphic output from these
>   software) was made from an unlicensed/pirated software?

No. In general the files created by the software such as Adobe Photoshop and Illustrator won’t have any signature connecting you to the source—and licensing status—of any software you use.

> If not then when these software providers will knew about it?

Since most all major software nowadays—such as Adobe products—“phone home” when you use it to check for updates or license validity, chances are high that when you first install it and get it running it will definitely be contacting the software publisher’s servers to check for updates and perform basic licensing checks.

The end result of this could be that the license you are using with this software will be blacklisted and eventually stop working. Or perhaps your IP address and system information will be shared with the software publisher and possibly be used in potential legal action against you and other pirates. Heck, a software publisher could use your IP address and invoke [DMCA](http://www.dmca.com) procedures to contact your ISP and have them surrender your personal contact info as a part of a larger legal action.

That’s the basic risk you run when you use illegally acquired software. And that is a risk which I personally consider to be a fairly major risk.